# Unable to establish wifi internet connection on new ubuntu installation

Tags: wireless, internet, connection

Computer: HP Stream Notebook 11.6" Intel Celeron CPU N2840.  WiFi was working in Windows, replaced Windows with Ubuntu 16.04.  I have no Ethernet connection, so have not been able to connect to the internet at all.  What I've tried: gone to Software & Updates/Available Drivers, 802 is selected.  I suspect the problem may lie in the Add/Edit Wifi connections box, in the Device field.  If that is for my computer's NIC MAC address, I have been unable to find it with `lshw` or `grep` commands because the portion of the resulting display which would contain my MAC is in the eth0 section, and I have no Ethernet connection. Suggestions and redirection welcome.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list:
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: ssb, wl

$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6, I ran the 2 commands you said, and have added the results to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You installed a wrong driver for your wireless device.

Connect to the internet by wire and run

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe b43
```

Your Wi-Fi should be working.